# Get a google api key for store description to show in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-api

i just got some project that i should get an store time(ex: open/close 10AM-10PM) at google. I have tried and search an API key to get the description from google but still dont know. Can anyone show me how to get this ? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can find nearby use Google Api like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

In search responses, you can get `"opening_hours"`